# Countdown click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I did a small countdown clock challenge in JavaScript. Please review it, thanks.

```js
const timeControls = document.querySelector('.timer__controls');
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('.display__time-left');
const endTime = document.querySelector('.display__end-time');
let interval;

function secondsToHourMinSec(seconds) {
  const date = new Date(0);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

function advanceCurrentTime(seconds) {
  const date = new Date(0);
  date.setSeconds(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + seconds);
  return date.toLocaleTimeString().substr(0, 7);
}

function displayRemainingTime(seconds) {
  timeLeft.textContent = secondsToHourMinSec(seconds);
}

function displayEndTime(seconds) {
  endTime.textContent = `Be back at ${advanceCurrentTime(seconds)}`;
}

function displayTime(seconds) {
  displayRemainingTime(seconds);
  displayEndTime(seconds);

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    displayRemainingTime(seconds);
  }, 1000);
}

function startTimer(seconds) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  displayTime(seconds);
}

timeControls.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const button = e.target.closest('button');
  if (button)
    startTimer(parseInt(button.dataset.time));
});

document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = this.minutes.value;
  if (value.length !== 0)
    startTimer(parseInt(value) * 60);
  this.reset();
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #8e24aa;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #42a5f5 0%, #478ed1 50%, #0d47a1 100%);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
}

.display__time-left {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.timer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.timer__controls {
  display: flex;
}

.timer__controls>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.timer__controls form {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.timer__controls input {
  flex: 1;
  border: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.timer__button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
}

.timer__button:hover,
.timer__button:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  outline: 0;
}

.display {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.display__end-time {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Countdown Timer</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="timer__controls">
      <button data-time="20" class="timer__button">20 Secs</button>
      <button data-time="300" class="timer__button">Work 5</button>
      <button data-time="900" class="timer__button">Quick 15</button>
      <button data-time="1200" class="timer__button">Snack 20</button>
      <button data-time="3600" class="timer__button">Lunch Break</button>
      <form name="customForm" id="custom">
        <input type="text" name="minutes" placeholder="Enter Minutes">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="display">
      <h1 class="display__time-left"></h1>
      <p class="display__end-time"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks great to me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following ideas for improvement of your code:

- Separate different concepts like timers and UI rendering to make them easy to understand and change.
- Use milliseconds for consistency with browser API.
- Separate formatting and calculation for dates and durations.
- Incapsulate mutable state in objects so it won't leak in your main application logic (`let interval`).
- Don't use the `substr` function to format time because this solution is not robust. Write custom formatter or use a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) instead.

Here is my solution:

```
class Timer {
    constructor(duration, delay = 1000) {
        this._remaining = duration;
        this._delay = delay;
        this._callbacks = [];
    }

    start() {
        this._intervalId = setInterval(this._tick.bind(this), this._delay);
    }

    stop() {
        clearInterval(this._intervalId);
    }

    onTick(callback) {
        this._callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    _tick() {
        this._remaining -= this._delay;
        if (this._remaining <= 0) this.stop();
        this._callbacks.forEach((cb) => cb(this._remaining));
    }
}

class Timers {
    makeActive(timer) {
        this._activeTimer = timer;
    }

    stopActive() {
        if (this._activeTimer) this._activeTimer.stop();
    }
}

// I didn't change formatting implementation here because I am lazy
const formatHMS = (date) => date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
const formatLocaleHMS = (date) => date.toLocaleTimeString().substr(0, 8);

const dateIn = (duration) => {
    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(Date.now() + duration);
    return date;
}

const durationToDate = (duration) => {
    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(duration);
    return date;
}

const timeControls = document.querySelector('.timer__controls');
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('.display__time-left');
const endTime = document.querySelector('.display__end-time');

const displayRemaining = (duration) => {
    timeLeft.textContent = formatHMS(durationToDate(duration));
}

const displayEnd = (duration) => {
    endTime.textContent = `Be back at ${formatLocaleHMS(dateIn(duration))}`;
}

const timers = new Timers();

const startAndUpdate = (duration) => {
    displayRemaining(duration);
    displayEnd(duration);

    const timer = new Timer(duration);
    timer.start();
    timer.onTick(displayRemaining);

    timers.stopActive();
    timers.makeActive(timer);
};

const secondsToMs = (seconds) => seconds * 1000;
timeControls.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const button = e.target.closest('button');
    if (button) startAndUpdate(secondsToMs(parseInt(button.dataset.time)));
});

const minutesToMs = (minutes) => secondsToMs(minutes * 60);
document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = this.minutes.value;
    if (value !== '') startAndUpdate(minutesToMs(parseInt(value)));
});
```

Comment: Using underscore to indicate private properties (though popular) is unsafe and is poor naming. Private must be enforced at a language level or it is pointless. Without enforcement you can not trust state and thus must code accordingly (you should consider them pubic and untrustable)

Comment: @Blindman67 it's just a convention because Javascript doesn't have private visibility. Actually, you can enforce it with a linter. What is your solution to this problem in Javascript?

Comment: I use closure inside object factories with heavy reliance on getters and setters to ensure a trustable state. The reason I made a comment is that the interval timer handle once lost can not be rediscovered (well not easily, it can be guessed but at the  risk of stopping other intervals) . As the code stands the interval timer represents a potential memory leak. Consider using `setTimeout`

Comment: @Blindman67 so are you saying that because `_intervalId ` is public anyone can change it and the handler can be lost?

Comment: Yes and that loss is unrecoverable, a memory leak.

Comment: @Blindman67 I rewrote the implementation for the timer with closure and posted it https://jsfiddle.net/segf84uz/. Is that it? I like it more than class implementation too but it has one drawback — each object instance has a unique set of functions (they are not shared across all objects).

Comment: Looks good. When defining objects one must consider the number of instances and how often these instances are created. Parsed functions are cached on all but the oldest browsers and closure across the functions is the shared factory's scope This question's requirements are for a single instance and as such there will be no additional overhead when compared to class syntax. I find that only when creating 1000's of objects per second (animations) does the class (prototype) syntax offer any detectable performance benefit.

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you for the advice. I will stick to the mutable state in closure in the future instead of using classes.

Comment: @blindman67 setTimeOut is also not a great alternative as it uses the unsafe eval() function under the hood.. https://idiallo.com/javascript/settimeout-and-setinterval-and-setevil

Comment: @RyanStone Only if you pass it a string,